# C/C++ with tree sitter: how to change indent?

Tags: indentation, c++, c, tree-sitter

I use Emacs with tree sitter for c++ code (`c++-ts-mode`).
With usual `c++-mode` I've used this fix for me:

```lisp
(c-set-offset 'inline-open '0)
```

but I don't understand how to do it in new `c++-ts-mode`.

In general I want an indent to be like this:

```cpp
void sort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) 
    {
        int a;
```

but now I get this:

```cpp
void sort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) 
        {
            int a;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to reuse most of an existing style so that your init.el does not add 100 new lines of indentation rules for every language.

For the C/C++ family, they provide a custom option to add your own function.

In my case, I reused the BSD style and added a few lines on my own.

```
(defun my-indent-style()
  "Override the built-in BSD indentation style with some additional rules"                                                             
  `(;; Here are your custom rules
    ((node-is ")") parent-bol 0)                                                                                                         
    ((match nil "argument_list" nil 1 1) parent-bol c-ts-mode-indent-offset)                                                                                   
    ((parent-is "argument_list") prev-sibling 0)                                                                                         
    ((match nil "parameter_list" nil 1 1) parent-bol c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
    ((parent-is "parameter_list") prev-sibling 0) 

    ;; Append here the indent style you want as base                                                                                       
   ,@(alist-get 'bsd (c-ts-mode--indent-styles 'cpp))))                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

(use-package c-ts-mode                                                                                                                       
 :if (treesit-language-available-p 'c)                                                                                                
 :custom                                                                                                                              
 (c-ts-mode-indent-offset 4)                                                                                                          
 (c-ts-mode-indent-style #'my-indent-style)                                                                                           
 :init                                                                                                                                          
 ;; Remap the standard C/C++ modes                                                                                                        
 (add-to-list 'major-mode-remap-alist '(c-mode . c-ts-mode))                                                                          
 (add-to-list 'major-mode-remap-alist '(c++-mode . c++-ts-mode))                                                                      
 (add-to-list 'major-mode-remap-alist '(c-or-c++-mode . c-or-c++-ts-mode)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a decent description of how "node-is" etc work. Rule order also seems to be important.

Comment: On my hand I followed this guide, which was really helpful : https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/admin/notes/tree-sitter/starter-guide?h=feature/tree-sitter

As for the order you can see this list as a bunch of if/else if/else statements, so if one of the first rules matches it will not process the following. Be sure to put your narrow rules first

Answer (score 2):

In general indent is controlled by `treesit-simple-indent-rules` variable.
Which (in new `c++-ts-mode`) is controlled by `c-ts-mode--indent-styles` function.

I had to redefine `c-ts-mode--indent-styles` adding those lines:

```
  ...
  ((parent-is "binary_expression") parent 0)

+ ((query "(do_statement body: (compound_statement) @indent)") parent-bol 0)
+ ((query "(do_statement \"while\" @indent)") parent-bol 0)
+ ((query "(if_statement consequence: (compound_statement) @indent)") parent-bol 0)
+ ((query "(for_statement body: (compound_statement) @indent)") parent-bol 0)

  ((query "(for_statement initializer: (_) @indent)") parent-bol 5)
  ...
```